# Inserting from an object into another object

Tags: plsql

From table abc i am inserting values in the object abc_type now i'm trying 
 to insert form abc_type to abc_second object on some condition.While doing 
 his i'm getting error that this is not a table.Is it even possible to fetch 
 data from an object and insert into another one.

```
create table abc(id number,name varchar2(50));
create or replace type abc_obj as object(id number,name varchar2(50) ) ;
create or replace type abc_ref as table of abc_obj;
declare 
abc_type abc_ref := abc_ref();
abc_second abc_ref := abc_ref();
begin
select abc_obj(id ,name) 
bulk collect into abc_type 
from abc;
insert into table(abc_second) select * from abc_type where id=1;
end;
```

Comment: do help if anyone know how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Oracle user the term "table" in 3, or more, totally different contexts. When you "create table ...' you build the definition of an object in which to persist data, this is the normal use for the term. However, when you use the form "... table of ...' you define an [pl/sql collection](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS00501) (array) for holding data inside pl/sql. In this case you have created a "nested table" (3rd use of table). (Note: Some collection types can be declared as column attributes on tables.) 
While not identical there are multiple issues with your object definitions as well. 
You did not explain the intended use for "second_table" but it seems you merely a
copy of the data from "abc". This can be achieved in multiple ways. If it is basically a one time process then just

```
create table second_table as select * from abc;
```

If this is an ongoing action then

```
    create table second_table as select * from abc where 1=0; 
    -- then when ever needed 
    insert into second_table select * from abc;
```

If neither of these satisfy your intended use please expand your question to explain the intended use.

Comment: what i want is to get data from table and insert into abc_typ and then from abc_typ i want it to insert into another object  abc_sec on some condition..i want to is this even possible and if it is how to do that

Comment: OK, your restatement merely restates how the code is laied out. It does  not actually describe/state the ultimate goal. But, it seems perhaps that goal is to create a table (standard term use) that contains an object column. Is the following a valid statement of the problem: Given a table with N columns create a new table of objects where each object contains the original N attributes.